# ms access vba supress duplicates when importing xml

Tags: vba, ms-access, import

Right now I import all the data and if I need to import it again it makes duplicates then I delete all the duplicates. I was wondering if there was a way to omit the duplicate records before importing.

```
Private Sub btnImport_Click()
Dim strFileName As String
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
Dim strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim daoRST As DAO.Recordset:
Dim xdoc As DOMDocument60

Set daoRST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("XSLT"): Debug.Print daoRST.Fields("XSL_Load").Value:

xslDoc.loadXML daoRST.Fields("XSL_Load").Value
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\*.xml"
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandle
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            ' INITIALIZE XML OBJECTS
            Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
            Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
            ' LOAD XML SOURCE
            xmlDoc.Load vrtSelectedItem
            ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
            xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
            newDoc.Save "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\temp.xml"

            ' APPEND TO TABLES
            On Error Resume Next

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''Try something like this?
            If xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID") =  rsR.Fields("ID").Value
                Then Resume Next
            Else
            ''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Application.ImportXML "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\temp.xml", acAppendData
        Next vrtSelectedItem
        Set daoRST = Nothing
    End If
End With

Set xmlDoc = Nothing
Set newDoc = Nothing
Set xslDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a primary key to the data set? Is there something that uniquely identifies a record? Alternatively, if multiple fields are used to determine if a record is unique you can consider adding a Composite Index to prevent duplicates. Here's a page I found on this topic: http://www.geeksengine.com/article/composite-unique-index-access.html

Comment: Thanks @RyanWildry I went with the Composite Index and that did the trick!